# .asp The data is not retrieved

Tags: python

I have a problem with my python that fetch HTML tag in the .asp file
First, input the selection tag on the asp website and then change it to the next asp page.

```
http://www.indexpr.moc.go.th/PRICE_PRESENT/Select_month_regionCsi.asp?region=3
```

must input the month, year, and province.

[image]

After that shows the asp browser what I like to see, I want to scrap the HTML tag inside the browser. And I found the problem on this below.

```
post_request = requests.post('http://www.indexpr.moc.go.th/PRICE_PRESENT/table_month_regionCsi.asp', data=payload).content
```

`soup = BeautifulSoup(post_request, 'html.parser')`

```
payload = {

'DDMonth': 4,
'DDYear': 2565,
'DDProvince': 50,
'texttable': 'csi_price_north_web_avg',
'text_name': 'unit_code_N',
```

}

In tag tr, it is not retrieved the data.

Here is the expect output

[image]

[image]

So what I get

```
<tr bgcolor="#fefefe"> ...empty... </tr>
```

[image]

Comment: If it is the BeautifulSoup scraping that is not working, why have you not shown us a single line of that code?